# Whitespace and parentheses in pointer declarations in Objective-C

Tags: objective-c, pointers, whitespace, declaration, parentheses

I understand from earlier questions that whitespace is irrelevant in pointer declarations in Objective-C, e.g:

```
float* powerPtr;

float * powerPtr;

float *powerPtr;
```

do mean exactly the same (apart from stylistic considerations...) but is

```
(float *)powerPtr;
```

(with parentheses) the same too? Don't these parentheses implicitly "mean" that the asterisk should be in some way related to *float*, when it should be instead more logically related to *powerPtr*? (The actual pointer is actually powerPtr, not float, if I am right)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your code:

```
(float *)powerPtr;
```

is not a valid *declaration* in (Objective-)C.

This is an *expression* which casts the value in the variable `powerPtr` to be of type `float *`.

The result of that cast is just discarded as it is not used, your compiler might give a warning - Xcode 8 issues an "Expression result unused".

**Addendum**

From your comment the syntax you show was meant to be part of a method declaration, e.g. something like:

```
- (void)doSomething:(float *)powerPtr;
```

that would occur in an `@interface`. The parentheses here are not being used for grouping *per se* but to delimit the type. As to you concern:

> Don't these parentheses implicitly "mean" that the asterisk should be in some way related to `float`, when it should be instead more logically related to `powerPtr`?

The `*` *is* part of the type, `float *` is the type specification for "pointer to float". The identifier `powerPtr` is associated with the whole type specification.

HTH

Comment: Isn't it used in method definitions?

Comment: - (BOOL)isEqualToString:(NSString *)other;

Comment: See addendum, HTH

Comment: Understood, so is it a proper syntax for methods in @interface?

Comment: Yes as the declaration ends with `;`, in the `@implementation` there is no `;` and in the same place the method body - `{ ... }`